# wrapfig in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, wrapfigure

The `\includegraphics` command can take an overlay parameter `<n>` in beamer. I'd like to do the same thing for `\wrapfig` to allow overlays of a wrapped figure. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I remember, I have done that, but the results weren't nice. I usually arrange graphics with the *columns* environment.

Answer (score 4):

I think that wrapfig in beamer isn't that good idea. I can rarely make wrapfig work in normal, article environment, let alone in beamer.

You can see what I needed and great answers there [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17121/beamer-in-columns-exposing-picture-in-one-column-before-and-after-text-in-other). You make 2 columns and you can play with image and text overlay :)