# Beamer: Independently layout blocks

Tags: beamer, layout

The one thing that always bothers me when creating slides in LaTeX using the `beamer` class is that the layout is very static. That means once everything has been placed on the slide (with a lot of work to figure out the correct combination of columns and what not) it typically takes a lot of work (again) to change the frame's layout afterwards (e.g. if one decided that that image should rather be bottom-left than top-right).

Thus I was wondering on how this could be improved. My journey let to this question of mine: [Beamer: Automatic image container](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/514727/beamer-automatic-image-container) that was focused on automatically positioning images on slides.

Having thought about this some more though it seems to me that it would be beneficial to have a way to tell LaTeX that my frame consists of several blocks. Each block can contain arbitrary content (text / image / ...). And then I would tell each block where I want it to go. Thus in dummy-code this would look something like this:

```
\begin{frame}
    \begin{magicBox}{top-left}
        Some content
    \end{magicBox}
    \begin{magicBox}{bottom-right}
        More content
    \end{magicBox}
\end{frame}
```

which should produce something like this:

```
|---------------------------------------|
|---------------|                       |
| Some content  |                       |
|---------------|                       |
|                                       |
|                                       |
|                                       |
|                       |---------------|
|                       |  More content |
|                       |---------------|
|---------------------------------------|
```

Most importantly I could easily change the layout on my slide by simply changing the layout directives for my independent boxes:

```
\begin{frame}
    \begin{magicBox}{bottom-right}
        Some content
    \end{magicBox}
    \begin{magicBox}{top-left}
        More content
    \end{magicBox}
\end{frame}
```

Yielding

```
|---------------------------------------|
|---------------|                       |
| More content  |                       |
|---------------|                       |
|                                       |
|                                       |
|                                       |
|                       |---------------|
|                       |  Some content |
|                       |---------------|
|---------------------------------------|
```

Note that I also want to be able to let boxes stagger on top of each other. That means that while I want LaTeX to do the layout inside the boxes, I don't want it to interfere with the boxes' positioning (this is the user's responsibility).

Where necessary it should be possible to give the box a fixed width (and height). If that is omitted the box should be as tall as LaTeX thinks the content should be (for text that would imply no line-breaking if no width is specified).

---

Now that I have described what I would like to have, let's focus on the actual question of mine: Are there packages and/or functionalities that provide this kind of feature?

I would also be happy about *similar* features that one might be able to use to build upon in order to make such a feature happen.

Note: I am aware that in Beamer's manual the `textpos` package is mentioned that allows to position its contents on a page absolutely. I guess this could definitely be used for this purpose if one find a way to map my relative layout instructions into absolute positions on the slide.

Then of course there's `TikZ` but it seems an overkill to create the entire slide as a tikzpicture in order to do some layout stuff...

Comment: Does it helps? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405674/1952 look also to other answers there.

Comment: @Ignasi yes that looks promising. Thanks!